# Script loading in span with help of jQuery with any action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, norton

I'm trying to load a javascript script link in div/span. Script must come inside span when I run the page. Once page get loaded script content will be shown in span.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>

</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
     {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "test.js"; //https link 
        // Use any selector
        $(".loader").append(s);
     });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
 <span class="loader">

  </span>
</body>
```

I am open to other solution also.

Comment: why only inside the loader? is it some kind of template?

Comment: And why does the script have to be in a span? If this is some third party script, for instance from facebook etc. they often use document.write or other methods that require the script to be loaded as the DOM loads, so inserting scripts like that dynamically won't work no matter what you try.

Comment: @adeneo: I can use other element also like div etc.Yes it is third party script but it is loading from same doamin.

Comment: Both document.write and document.writeln method should output text into an unready (open) document.When the page finishes loading, the document becomes closed. An attempt to document.write in it will cause the contents to be erased.

Comment: Why was this tagged with 'norton'?

Answer (score -1):

The only problem I saw in your code that is the source of jquery is incorrect because it is using **https** and the order parameters of the script tag

Try substituting the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: But this way your script will not run unless other methods to create call test.js

Comment: I do not know why they gave me a vote unless in my answer. Because the question was about loading a script in a span, and not the the script would work